# Javascript Promise chain not executing next then()

Tags: javascript, promise

Here's my example code:

```
function recursiveFetch(num) {
    // EXAMPLE that recursivley fetches all todos from example API
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + num)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                if (num == 0) {
                    console.log("Done getting TODOs");
                    resolve(num);
                } else {
                    recursiveFetch(num - 1);
                }
            });
    });
}

new Promise(resolve => {
        // Just using this for this example
        resolve(10);
    })
    .then((num) => {
        // This runs fine and returns a promise which is eventually resolved
        return recursiveFetch(num);
    })
    .then((num) => {
        // This never happens?
        console.log("num is now " + num);
    })
```

I can't tell why but the second `.then` is never run.

If I execute this code in the Firefox console I get the output `Done getting TODOs` but the `"num is now "` log is never called?

Comment: Try adding a `.catch` to see if there are any errors. (also, best to avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern). You also aren't calling `resolve` in the `else`, the Promise will hang forever in that case

Comment: there's no need to create a new promise with `fetch`

Comment: @DanielA.White If I remove the `new Promise` line and the `resolve`, I get this output:
`num is now undefined`
`Done getting TODOs`, like it's just skipping the fact that it's a promise

Comment: Yes, according with [Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white)... `fetch` is a promise by default... it's not necessary  do a promise of another promise.

Comment: just keep `return`ing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code as it is, you need

```
recursiveFetch(num - 1).then(resolve)
```

However, there are quite a few mistakes, how about this cleaned-up one:

```js
async function fetchAll(num) {
  let data = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    let t = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + i);
    data.push(await t.json())
  }
  return data;
}

Promise
  .resolve(3)
  .then(fetchAll)
  .then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a resolve inside the "else" when you call recursively the function "recursiveFecth". Since the function is returning another promise you need to resolve then, otherwise it will exit inmediately.

I've tried it and it works:

```
function recursiveFetch(num) {
    // EXAMPLE that recursivley fetches all todos from example API
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + num)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                if (num == 0) {
                    console.log("Done getting TODOs");
                    resolve(num);
                } else {
                    resolve(recursiveFetch(num - 1));
                }
            });
    });
}

new Promise(resolve => {
        // Just using this for this example
        resolve(10);
    })
    .then((num) => {
        // This runs fine and returns a promise which is eventually resolved
        return recursiveFetch(num);
    })
    .then((num) => {
        // This never happens?
        console.log("num is now " + num);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the recursiveFetch in the inner promise

```
...
.then((data) => {
            if (num == 0) {
                console.log("Done getting TODOs");
                resolve(num);
            } else {
                return recursiveFetch(num - 1);
            }
        });
```